# What's the best way to inspect an attribute before setting it?

Tags: python

I have a need to inspect attributes before they are set<sup>†</sup>. A naive implementation would be something like:

```
class C(object):
    x = 5

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if hasattr(self, name):
            x = getattr(self, name)

            if x == 5:
                print 'do something'
        object.__setattr__(self, name , value)
```

However, this would trigger the class' `__getattribute__` method, which *must* be avoid here. From what i can tell, searching in the class' `__dict__` directly might do the trick; but as this is a class that's meant to be subclassed by the user, i imagine that `__slots__` and the MRO could add complications down the road.

Given these considerations, what's the best way to inspect an attribute before setting it?

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>In the interest of full disclosure, this class is actually going to be written as a `C` extension; however, i don't imagine the strategy deviating too much from the python implementation for that to matter.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) decorator?

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 5 # Default, for all
        # Future updates should be done with self.x = ...
        # To go through the approval below

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        if value == 5:
            print 'do something'
        else:
            self._x = value
```